# PhpStorm: manually force hard wrapping on specific chained methods or an array definition

Tags: phpstorm

I'm looking for a shortcut in PhpStorm to turn this:

```
$object->method()->method()->method();
```

into this:

```
$object->method()
       ->method()
       ->method();
```

and this:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

into this:

```
$array = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
];
```

Basically, I'm looking for a shortcut for the formatter to treat the current line as if it was over the "Hard wrap at" limit. It seems like such a shortcut should exist, but I can't find it. I don't want to turn wrapping "always" on, I'm looking to arbitrarily decide which should wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a shortcut in PhpStorm to turn this:
>
> ```php
> $object->method()->method()->method();
> ```
>
> into this:
>
> ```php
> $object->method()
>        ->method()
>        ->method();
> ```

There is no dedicated action for this. At very least I'm not aware of any.

You may only configure Code Style for PHP to place 2nd+ chainable call on a separate line.

- Settings/Preferences
- Editor | Code Style | PHP
- Wrapping and Braces | Chained method calls

[image]

---

> and this:
>
> ```php
> $array = [1,2,3,4,5];
> ```
>
> into this:
>
> ```php
> $array = [
>     1,
>     2,
>     3,
>     4,
>     5,
> ];
> ```

There is an intention to switch from one to another (and other way around). Will work for arrays as well as function/method call parameters.

It's accessible from Intentions/Quick Fix menu (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> or click on the light bulb).

[image]

[image]

**P.S.** Since 2022.1 or so version you can assign a shortcut to the actual Intention. Can be done right there from that menu:

[image]